# Magento 2: Property "ActionsHintLabel" does not have accessor method "getActionsHintLabel" in class "Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface"

Tags: magento2, rest-api, sales

In Magento 2 I am trying to add SalesRule from API: `/rest/V1/SalesRules`
Post Request body:

```
{
    "rule": { 
    "name": "Test SalesRule",
    "store_labels": [],
    "description": "test 50% discount",
            "website_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "customer_group_ids": [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                5,
                6
            ],
            "from_date": "2019-02-26",
            "to_date": "2019-03-05",
            "uses_per_customer": 1,
            "is_active": true,
            "condition": {
                "condition_type": "Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine",
                "aggregator_type": "any",
                "operator": null,
                "value": "1"
            },
            "action_condition": {
                "condition_type": "Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Combine",
                "aggregator_type": "all",
                "operator": null,
                "value": "1"
            },
            "stop_rules_processing": false,
            "is_advanced": true,
            "sort_order": 1,
            "simple_action": "cart_fixed",
            "discount_amount": 25,
            "discount_qty": 1,
            "discount_step": 0,
            "apply_to_shipping": false,
            "times_used": 0,
            "is_rss": false,
            "coupon_type": "SPECIFIC_COUPON",
            "use_auto_generation": false,
            "uses_per_coupon": 500,
            "simple_free_shipping": "0"
    }
}
```

But it gives me an error which says

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'actions_hint_label' cannot be null.

When I add this field and gave it some value 1, 0 or something it gives me an error like

> Property "ActionsHintLabel" does not have accessor method
>   "getActionsHintLabel" in class
>   "Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface".

Do you have any clue about that? and how to resolve that issue? 
thanks for reading, thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, every data provider interface is rewritten by a model class.

If you Check `di.xml` of `Magento_SalesRule` of then you will find that `Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface` is overridde by `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Data\Rule`.

So, is this class, might be `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Data\Rule` override by other class of any 3rd party module where might be `ActionsHintLabel` define. But this wrong way to rewrite a data model class.

Or may there are some [Extension attribute](https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html) concept build on `Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface` and use for some additional work.

> So, you have to check `extension_attributes.xml` of your 3rd party
>   module's  `extension_attributes.xml`   and find the solution by removing
>   this extension attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Examine input data and compare your data with Magento\SalesRule\Api\ Data\RuleInterface

For example, you must enter the product ID in the array design

Some input functions have an array of specific objects
Note the input of data to the functions